# Best way to count page viewed by perticular users in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Is there any other way to count hits rather then inserting every time in database ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079241/what-is-the-best-way-to-capture-page-views-per-user-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: i had already watched that post , Are you know which technique used by stackoverflow to count page views ?

Comment: Well, the answer given by Shane Courtrille, provides you with implementation of what you want, i think.